# Linux permissions -- can't write to directory which has all permissions set to allow all

Tags: linux, permissions

Scenario:

bob owns directory x

bob has set permissions on x to 777

jim can't write to x. Why?

Actual output:

```
ls -la .pip/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 user1 user1 4096 May  5 12:03 .
drwx------ 5 user1 user1 4096 May  6 11:34 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user1 user1 2054 May  5 12:48 pip.log

sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "apache"  /bin/bash -l -c "mkdir .pip/monkey"
/bin/bash: /home/user1/.bash_profile: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `.pip/monkey': Permission denied
```

Ultimately I'm trying to pip install as `apache` user and that user is not allowed to write the install log, so the process fails. I need to write the log as apache user, but it lives in my user space. I could change the owner, but this process is supposed to work for any user, even new ones, so it's somewhat confusing what I'm supposed to do to achieve this.

**UPDATE:**

I understand from http://linux.die.net/man/2/path_resolution that it is the fact that `apache` does not own `user1`'s home directory, so the directory search won't work. Is this the case?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to `mkdir` a directory within user1's home directory tree, but your question does not clearly identify where you are working.  Put in `pwd` output for reference.  The fact that `..` does not have group or world permissions appears to be a reason that you cannot work under /home/user1's directory tree as apache has no rights to pass through that level of the file system.  Please be more clear about what the directory tree looks like.  Also, `ls -lZ` and `getfacl` will help show people whether other permission issues may exist.

Comment: Who are jim and bob, and how do they relate to this question?  The only users I see mentioned are user1 and apache.  Please write the question so it is internally consistent.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:***  At the time this answer was composed, the question did not clearly identify working directories.  If assumptions documented in the answer are incorrect, the folders mentioned in the answer may need to be adapted accordingly.

It appears that the question asks why user `apache` cannot operate under:

```
/home/user1/
```

It also appears that `/home/user1` may have permissions set to `drwx------` as these permissions are typically used to help secure private data that can accumulate in the root of the user's home directory.

If the above is true, then it is normal for `apache` to not be able to work under `/home/user1/` because it does not have `traversal` rights to `/home/user`.  Such rights can be added in various ways.  The simplest, but not particularly safe way to do it is something like:

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/user1
```

It would then be possible for `/home/user1` sub-folder permissions to be tightened and loosened to fit the need.  It would be better to use group permissions than world permissions, but you should probably create a special group for this purpose rather than making `apache` a member of the `user1` group.  An even better solution would be to use an ACL that grants `apache` traversal rights to `/home/user1` without opening the user's home directory up to a wider audience.

Be careful.  Loosening permissions with the aforementioned command can give all users on the box access to sub-directories of the user's home directory if their permissions are not suitably tight.

***Note:***  Security mechanisms on some systems might get annoyed by loosening of user home directory permissions and interfere with manual overrides.  This could happen, for example, on a distribution that has `msec` configured to a relatively high security level.  Without more detail given about the system configuration, it is somewhat difficult to anticipate potential problems.  For example, unless an exception has been made for particular file system areas, on an `msec` managed system with high security set, `msec` will periodically rewrite directory permissions that it monitors if it does not consider the permissions compatible with the configured security level.